# How can I reduce the Complexity of this code?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

I'm trying to create a search method by DTO. I mean users can search products by one more field. Can you suggest any better way for that or help to reduce the complexity of this one?

```java
public List<ProductDTO> search(SearchProductDTO productDTO) {
    Criteria criteria = null;
    String insensitive = "i";
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getName()))
        criteria = Criteria.where(NAME.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getName(), insensitive);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getDescription()))
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(DESCRIPTION.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getDescription(), insensitive) : Criteria.where(DESCRIPTION.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getDescription(), insensitive);
    if (productDTO.getPrice() != 0)
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(PRICE.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getPrice()) : Criteria.where(PRICE.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getPrice());
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getBrand()))
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(BRAND.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getBrand(), insensitive) : Criteria.where(BRAND.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getBrand(), insensitive);
    if (productDTO.getProductSize() != null)
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(SIZE.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getProductSize()) : Criteria.where(SIZE.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getProductSize());
    if (productDTO.getStockCount() != 0)
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(STOCK_COUNT.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getStockCount()) : Criteria.where(STOCK_COUNT.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getStockCount());
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getType()))
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(TYPE.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getType(), insensitive) : Criteria.where(TYPE.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getType(), insensitive);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getColor()))
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(COLOR.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getColor(), insensitive) : Criteria.where(COLOR.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getColor(), insensitive);
    if (productDTO.getGender() != null)
        criteria = criteria != null ? criteria.and(GENDER.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getGender()) : Criteria.where(GENDER.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getGender());
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(productDTO.getPage(), productDTO.getSize());
    Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
    query = criteria != null ? query.addCriteria(criteria).with(pageable) : query;
    List<Product> products = mongoTemplate.find(query, Product.class);
    return products.stream().map(productMapper::modelToDto).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Format your code and share with some detail

Comment: I'm trying to create search method by DTO. And I cant anything about to do that. That's why I wrote spaghetti code((

Comment: Your code is correctly written in best way. Just put round bracket as below for better reading.

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getDescription()))
            criteria = (criteria != null ? criteria.and(DESCRIPTION.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getDescription(), insensitive) : Criteria.where(DESCRIPTION.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getDescription(), insensitive));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of null-checks by dynamically collecting criterias into list and combining this list into single "multi"-criteria

```java
List<Criteria> criterias = new ArrayList<>();

// collect
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getName()))
    criterias.add(Criteria.where(NAME.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getName(), insensitive));
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(productDTO.getDescription()))
    criterias.add(Criteria.where(DESCRIPTION.getLabel()).regex(productDTO.getDescription(), insensitive));
if (productDTO.getPrice() != 0)
    criterias.add(Criteria.where(PRICE.getLabel()).is(productDTO.getPrice()));
// and so on ...

// combine
Criteria multiCriteria = new Criteria().andOperator(criterias.toArray(new Criteria[criterias.size()]));

// use
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(productDTO.getPage(), productDTO.getSize());
Query query = new Query().with(pageable);
query.addCriteria(multiCriteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

One nicer thing to do would be to externalize the null check + appending of where clause + assignment of parameters into it‘s own method. This way your code will be more understandable.

You could also wrap the Criteria class and add for example „optionalWhere()“ which does the null check and appends the where clause only if the parameter has a value.

...Unfortunately I don‘t know why the problem of dynamic queries, as for searches from a GUI, are not addressed in the APi itself...